# Last.FM API in JavaScript - Error Code 5 appearing for some tracks?

Tags: javascript, api, last.fm

I am trying to implement Last.FM API using a JavaScript wrapper made by ['leemm'](https://github.com/leemm/last.fm.api), and it seems to function properly, with it returning information through testing. But when I try to use the 'track.getInfo()' method, it starts to throw

```
error: {
    code: '5',
    message: "Invalid format - This service doesn't exist in that format"
  },
  text: undefined
}
```

For songs such as 'Survival of The Fittest' by 'Mobb Deep'. But it returns information properly for other songs such as 'HUMBLE.' by 'Kendrick Lamar'.

This is my function:

```js
async function lastFMTest(){
  const data = await lastfm.track.getInfo({
    artist: 'Kendrick Lamar',
    track: 'HUMBLE.',
    username: 'NAG_Z',
    autocorrect: '1'
  });
  console.log(data.track.name, data.track.userplaycount, data.track.toptags.tag[0].name);
}
```

I noticed that *getInfo()* method returns information for a good amount of tracks before crashing on one particular track. I checked the [unofficial documentation](https://lastfm-docs.github.io/api-docs/codes/) and it says:

> #### Last.fm Error Code 5: Invalid Response Format
>
> A `format` parameter is necessary in addition to the documented parameters, this may either have a value of `XML` or `JSON` (case insensitive). Requesting data in another format will emit this error. Some methods do support more than these 2 formats, the methods that do have their formats listed in this documentation.

So I tried inserting a `format` parameter specifying `'json'` which results in the same issue, `'XML'` breaks the method though I do wish my data returned in JSON format so I don't really think *XML* is the way to go.

This is most likely due to my lack of understanding of the API or possibly JavaScript as I am still a novice, if anyone could help me I would greatly appreciate it!

### EDIT:

For the `format` parameter I tried both 'json' and 'JSON', doesn't work even afterward.

Comment: Did you specify `'json'` or `'JSON'`? I know it says it's case-insensitive but why not try anyway!

Comment: Was there anything in the official documentation: https://www.last.fm/api/rest

Comment: Unfortunately, it still doesn't work any matter if JSON is capitalised or not (updating my post to reflect this), and official documentation does not say anything about the errors except for what they mean

Comment: I get an error when I use `JSON` instead of `json` in a plain curl call. Also looking at the source code of that library it already adds `format=json` automatically to all calls. Maybe you can enable debugging for that library in the options. That should print out the API urls which you could execute with curl from the command line. **Could** you post the song where the API returns the error? Or does it happen for all songs?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this matters; but I went to the url for each song

Click "Play Track" and it plays
https://www.last.fm/music/Kendrick+Lamar/_/HUMBLE.

Click "Play Track" and it says "Track unavailable."
https://www.last.fm/music/Mobb+Deep/_/Survival+of+the+Fittest

So maybe something is going on within the leemm wrapper for last.fm? If I go to the api directly via `audioscrobbler`, I get a response

[image]

Then I went to the album info and got several tracks

[image]

Following that, the LP Version doesn't seem to have a track at all.
https://www.last.fm/music/Mobb+Deep/_/Survival+of+the+Fittest+(LP+Version)

And the other urls that are in the api response:
https://www.last.fm/music/Mobb+Deep/_/Survival+Of+The+Fittest+(Remix)+(Extended+Version)

https://www.last.fm/music/Mobb+Deep/_/Survival+Of+The+Fittest+(Remix)+(Instrumental)

This one has a track, says "Track unavailable" when playingg
https://www.last.fm/music/Mobb+Deep/_/Survival+Of+The+Fittest+(A+Cappella)